# C#: Update subtotal textbox instantaneously given 4 combobox selections

Tags: c#, combobox, textbox

This is my first post on StackOverflow, be kind :D!

I am developing a restaurant bill calculator for class. Given user input on four comboboxes: Beverage, Appetizer, Main Course & Dessert, I am having the code calculate the subtotal, tax and total. For each combobox, I have a list of predefined items and values associated with each item. I've been able to code this successfully. As the user selects their items, I have my subtotal, tip & total textboxes automatically update. Subtotal = bevPrice + appPrice + mainPrice + dessPrice. Tax = subtotal * .1M. Total = subtotal + tax.

My issue: say a user inputs their selections for each category (beverage, app, main, dessert). Then, let's say the user goes back to the beverage (combobox1) and decides to change it from one option to another. My code zeros out the other selections even though an option has been selected. Similarly, say a user inputs all four selections, then goes back to change their main course (combobox3), my code saves combobox1 & 2 (beverage & appetizer), adds in the newly selected main course, but zeros out combobox4 (dessert).

I know this issue is coming up because of the selectionindexchanged event handler. If combobox2's selection is changed, then it calcs combobox 1 & 2, but a change hasn't occurred in combobox3 & 4 so it reverts it to a 0 value. Right?

I'm sure the answer is obvious, but I am a novice. Thanks!

Anyways, here's a preview of my code (sorry, I'm so longwinded):

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Menu bevSelect = comboBox1.SelectedItem as Menu;
        textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(bevSelect.bevPrice);

    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Menu appSelect = comboBox2.SelectedItem as Menu;
        Menu bevSelect = comboBox1.SelectedItem as Menu;
        textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(bevSelect.bevPrice + appSelect.appPrice);
    }

    private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Menu mainSelect = comboBox3.SelectedItem as Menu;
        Menu appSelect = comboBox2.SelectedItem as Menu;
        Menu bevSelect = comboBox1.SelectedItem as Menu;
        textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(bevSelect.bevPrice + appSelect.appPrice + mainSelect.mainPrice);
    }

    private void comboBox4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Menu dessSelect = comboBox4.SelectedItem as Menu;
        Menu mainSelect = comboBox3.SelectedItem as Menu;
        Menu appSelect = comboBox2.SelectedItem as Menu;
        Menu bevSelect = comboBox1.SelectedItem as Menu;
        textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(bevSelect.bevPrice + appSelect.appPrice + mainSelect.mainPrice + dessSelect.dessPrice);
```

And here's [a video](https://youtu.be/4M9f_EKORzU)!

Comment: Just check every combo box whenever any of them are changed.

Comment: I'm  not sure what the question is here. It appears you're asking **us** to explain to **you** the code **you wrote**. Is that correct?

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry for the ambiguity, I wanted to know why it _isn't_ working out of order and how to fix it, but I've come up with a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This happening because on your first handler you fill the textbox only with calculations from first combo box. You should make a function that calculates your bill based on all 4 selected items and you should call it in your SelectedIndexChanged handler. Basically your method should do what your last handler does.

```
private void comboBox1/2/3/4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  calculateBill();
}

private void calculateBill()
{
    Menu dessSelect = comboBox4.SelectedItem as Menu;
    Menu mainSelect = comboBox3.SelectedItem as Menu;
    Menu appSelect = comboBox2.SelectedItem as Menu;
    Menu bevSelect = comboBox1.SelectedItem as Menu;
    textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(bevSelect.bevPrice + appSelect.appPrice + mainSelect.mainPrice + dessSelect.dessPrice);
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. I was just about to hit submit on my answer lol.

Comment: I am getting a "System.NullReferenceException" on textbox3.Text = Convert.ToString(x+y...+z)